# How to stretch UITextViews in UIScrollView to fit horizontal size after rotation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uitextview

So I have a long form with 11 UITextViews. It's just long enough exceed the iPhone older 3.2" screen so I had to throw it all in a UIScrollView. Now when I rotate to horizontal the UITextViews won't resize to fit the newly available space to the left.

Any ideas about how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

First, do you mean UITextFields? (instead of TextViews)

There are many different ways to go about this.

First of, did you use Interface Builder to build the view?

If the view is simple, you can try the elastic positioning provided by Interface Builder, you might have to fiddle with different options.

Another way is to use Autolayout system, available in iOS 6.0+

Or, if you're comfortable with handling frames yourself with codes, you can have different frame sizes set for when the view has rotated.

Or, you can create a separate xib file just for the landscape view and have the program load that xib when the phone rotated.

All of the above are widely used methods for handling rotations, you should choose what fits best in your situation.